# Guiders.js - Guider Showing Over Element

Tags: javascript, guiders.js

I Have A Guider That Is Showing Over The Element It Is Attached To, Like So:

[image: Guider In Relation To Element]

My Code For The Guider Is:

```
guiders.createGuider({
    title:"Flosses",
    description:"Strawberry Floss Is All About Flosses, We Have Made One For You, Why Not View It Now?",
    id:"2",
    buttons:[],
    attachTo:"#firstFloss",
    position:6
});
```

I would like the guider down maybe 100px or so, allowing me to see the element It is attached to.

Thanks,
Ari

Comment: And where is the problem? What have you tried to solve that problem?

Comment: @Zim84: Yes I Have Tried. And No, I Have No Idea Where the problem is, probobly in the CSS

Comment: Lets write it in other words: What is happening with your current code and what _should_ happen with your desired code?

Comment: @Zim84 I added That Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS you can use the parameter `offset: { left:0, top: -10 }` to adjust the exact position. But it looks like your guide is centered on top of the item. Is that intended? Check if you target the correct element with `attachTo`